# Low level IO in linux kernel

Tags: linux, io, kernel, dma

I am writing a driver for a device that generates a bunch of data and stores its in a memory buffer. Driver should read this buffer and store data to a nvme storage. Device and memory buffer are implemented in fpga logic. The buffer size is about 1G. CPU sees it like a regular ram but linux know nothing about it and this is a problem. When I use bio layer in order to save the data I need a strust* page pointer but I don’t have one.
The question is:
Is there any way to save the data from the buffer using just a physical address and size?
Or I have to use pages so I need to add this buffer to linux memory pool somehow.

Comment: Is it PCIe? Does it have BARs?

Comment: You are creating a NVMe-based storage, is that correct? If you are using FPGA I assume it should be from Xilinx. If so, Xilinx has some tutorials on how to create such a bridge to expose the flash memories through the PCIe over the FPGA. Anyway, you are going to need to write a driver for the device, and you can bypass the page-cache, so you do not need to use the `struct page` stuff.

Comment: I have no problem with nvme devices. Xilinx did all the dirty job by writing a driver and I see them as regular block devices (/dev/nvme*). The problem with fpga-based memory buffer which linux know nothing about and so cannot perform any IO operation(or I just don’t know how to do it). The question is how can I “hotplug” this buffer to the linux memory pool and allocate it in the driver for IO.